# I am unable to add identifiers to segues. Is there a way to repair a ios xamarin storyboard?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, storyboard, segue

I have been working with Xamarin since August and it has worked fine until recently. Our storyboards do not allow us to name newly created segues. I am only able to see some of the previously named segues in properties window. However if i open the storyboard using xcode it works fine. Why does this not work in Xamarin studio? Does anyone have a fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click the storyboard and open it up in Source Code Editor.

Check that the XML matches up correctly, and identify the segues that you can't see.